# Parsing a list of Bitrise YAML key/values as Go structs

Tags: go, continuous-integration, yaml, bitrise

I'm currently working on a Bitrise workflow step, and I'm trying to allow for the step give the user a way to provide a list of optional YAML key/value pairs for a specific step input, currently trying to implement as:

```
my_step@1:
    inputs:
        - uri_actions:
            - button_text: Some text
              uri: www.google.com
            - button_text: Some text 2
              uri: www.google2.com
            - button_text: Some text 3
              uri: www.google3.com
```

and then attempting to parse in Go as structs:

```
type config struct {
    UriActionList []UriAction `env:"uri_actions"`
}

type UriAction struct {
    ButtonText string `env:"button_text"`
    Uri        string `env:"uri"`
}
```

and have also tried mapping the `config` struct as variations of

```
type config struct {
    UriActionList map[UriAction]string `env:"uri_actions"`
}
```

The Bitrise step uses `stepconf` to automatically parse the users' workflow and map the YAML to the declared `structs`:

```
func main() {
  var cfg config
  if err := stepconf.Parse(&cfg); err != nil {
      fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Error: %s\n", err)
      os.Exit(1)
  }
  stepconf.Print(cfg)
}
```

But neither of which are playing nice at all..

This is my first venture into Go and developing my own Bitrise step, so what am I doing wrong? Or Is there a more civilised way to go about this achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: As per discussion in comments this question is related to `go-steputils/stepconf` library to do parsing of yaml. But that library doesn't operate on yaml files at all and simply parses environment with some sugar to handle collections (see the library usage [example](https://github.com/bitrise-io/go-steputils/blob/master/stepconf/example_test.go) and [test](https://github.com/bitrise-io/go-steputils/blob/master/stepconf/stepconf_test.go)). My guess is there's some plumbing somewhere which converts yaml to env variables.

If you intend to read yaml from file without that plumbing I'd recommend using well documented library for that purpose - [`go-yaml`](https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml) as per following example:

```golang
type config struct {
    Inputs []Inputs `yaml:"inputs"`
}

type Inputs struct {
    UriActionList []UriAction `yaml:"uri_actions"`
}

type UriAction struct {
    ButtonText string `yaml:"button_text"`
    Uri        string `yaml:"uri"`
}

func main() {
    cfg := config{}

    err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &cfg)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error: %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("---\n%v\n", cfg)
}
```

See playground with working code [here](https://play.golang.org/p/JanQ3rRjRYN)

Comment: Ah apologies, I should have added that I'm currently using `stepconf` to parse the bitrise.yml file. The parsing function is:

`if err := stepconf.Parse(&cfg); err != nil {`
  `fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Error: %s\n", err)`
`os.Exit(1)`

Comment: I am not familiar with `stepconf` Let me take a look and modify my answer accordingly.

Comment: It seems that that library does not work with YAML at all. It parses environmental variables as per what I can see in their (undocumented) code. If you really want just read YAML file and don't care about that plumbing I'd still use go-yaml. But I understand it might not be answer to question anymore. I updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: hmm yes it seems so.. just found this buried in the Bitrise steps documentation stating that "Step input values are strings: the Bitrise CLI exposes the Step inputs as Environment Variables to the Steps."

https://devcenter.bitrise.io/contributors/create-your-own-step/#step-input-keys-and-values

So based off that, it seems like I may not be able to nest a YAML flow mapping to an input value.. :/

Answer (score 0):

Step inputs can only be strings/texts as those are passed as Environment Variables to the steps, and environment variables can only be texts. You can of course include a yml structure in the string but it still have to be a string.

So, instead of your original

```yaml
my_step@1:
    inputs:
        - uri_actions:
            - button_text: Some text
              uri: www.google.com
            - button_text: Some text 2
              uri: www.google2.com
            - button_text: Some text 3
              uri: www.google3.com
```

make the value of `uri_actions` a string (via a `|`):

```yaml
my_step@1:
  inputs:
    - uri_actions: |
        - button_text: Some text
          uri: www.google.com
        - button_text: Some text 2
          uri: www.google2.com
        - button_text: Some text 3
          uri: www.google3.com
```

then in your step you can read the Environment Variable `uri_actions` which will hold the value (as string):

```
- button_text: Some text
  uri: www.google.com
- button_text: Some text 2
  uri: www.google2.com
- button_text: Some text 3
  uri: www.google3.com
```

If you want to parse this as YML you can do that the way @blami mentioned:

```
uriActionsUserInput := os.Getenv("uri_actions")
cfg := []UriAction{}
err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(uriActionsUserInput), &cfg)
```

See a complete example here: https://play.golang.org/p/qst3oVnjK0X